# Make a responsive image only shrink as needed

Tags: css

In my web application, I have many images. They either have width specified in the style attribute (in pixels). Or they dont have size specified. I would like to make them responsive, but they should never get larger than specified width or their actual width even though the parent container may be larger.

Please note that the images are added by users. I cannot add specific styles for each image. I hope to apply some general style rules to all these images.

Is this doable?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: use max-width:100%; property and give a try

Comment: Chandra, this seems to work. If you can make it an answer post, I will select it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `max-width` property.

CSS

```
img{
max-width:100%;
}
```

Style Accordingly.

Hope this Helps..

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using CSS max-width property

Add this in your template CSS file

```
img{max-width:100%;}
```